# asynchronous web development with django. too much technologies

Tags: python, django, asynchronous

I've just started with asynchronous web development (Django) and I am a little confused. There is so much technologies and I don't know what is the best choice.

In my app I need real-time communication between server and client (I'm going to use WebSocket with Django Channels - I think this is a good option, isn't it?) But maybe asyncio lib would be better?

On the second way, I need something to doing background task. (sending mass emails, thumbnailing photo, etc) What I should chose? Celery? asyncio lib? New thread or process for that? Or maybe Django Channels can doing stuff like this?

Could you guys explain me when use asycio lib, when Celery (or other tasks queue tool), and when multithreading / multiprocessing?

I am so confused with this all techniques.

Answer (score 0):

For websockets try aiohtpp. http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/. It supports async/await syntax.
For asynchronous tasks Celery and RabbitMQ (as message broker) is good choice.